# How configure server for post method work properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, postman, laravel-5.8

In ubuntu server I make this test route in **api.php**

```
Route::post('/test', function () {
    return response()->json(['a' => 'b']);
})->name('test');
```

When I send post request I get this error

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

But If I edit **api.php** to

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return response()->json(['a' => 'b']);
})->name('test');
```

That case if I send **post** or **get** method in postman get correct result

```
{"a":"b"}
```

This is happen only server. What need to configure?

[image: see postman image]

Comment: Show us how you're sending the POST request. I suspect you aren't doing it correctly, and it's defaulting back to GET. No server config should be required for this.

Comment: I use postman to send post request

Comment: @Davit could you attrach an screenshot of your Postman request?

Comment: That has digest auth and I did not want show that

Comment: @Davit So censor that bit.

Comment: @HCK I add postman request

Answer (score 2):

I tested the same `Route` method with my own remote server and a local server. It ran flawlessly on local server, but on remote server it threw

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

After a while i changed my url from '**http**' to '**https**' and it worked.

after digging deeper i found that in order to interact with different server the protocol must use **HTTPS**. But if the application is on same server you can work with  **HTTP**.

Comment: I add headers but that case I get error as json `{
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException",
    "file": "/home/forge/vininfo-prelive.omnicodeprojects.com/releases/20190517183620/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
    "line": 255,
    "trace": [
        {.........`

Comment: @Davit i just ran your test route on my postman, it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I have to server. I did not know the differnece. But this code for one server not work

Comment: I have two server. I did not know the difference. But this code for one server not work

Comment: Let me check it on a server, hold on.

Comment: I can not send you credentials

Comment: @Davit i figured out how to run it on my remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with postman. I change type to json and it worked for me.
I assume you are using POST method in postman ofc.

Hope it helps :D